# Cохранение картинок на внешнюю (SD карту) память. Код написал, результата нет!

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-file

В массиве 10 картинок(ссылки), Скачиваю и сохраняю на внешнюю SD карту. (Так должно быть)

Получается по другому: Папка на внешней памяти создается, а картинки туда не грузятся И ЕЩЕ как то создается папка во внутренней памяти телефона и картинки грузятся туда. Вот лог

```
04-04 01:27:17.253 7241-7241/com.example.user.home10_3 
E/Zygote: Zygote:  error closing descriptor
libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:221)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:715)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 01:27:19.750 7241-7241/com.example.user.home10_3 E/ffi_jank: timespan = 30.89546
```

код

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView textView;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add("http://startandroid.ru/images/stories/pic/banner2_170.png");
        arrayList.add("http://startandroid.ru/images/stories/pic/banner2_170.png");
        arrayList.add("http://startandroid.ru/images/stories/pic/banner2_170.png");
        arrayList.add("http://startandroid.ru/images/stories/pic/banner2_170.png");
        arrayList.add("http://startandroid.ru/images/stories/pic/banner2_170.png");
        arrayList.add("http://startandroid.ru/images/stories/pic/banner2_170.png");
        arrayList.add("http://startandroid.ru/images/stories/pic/banner2_170.png");
        arrayList.add("http://startandroid.ru/images/stories/pic/banner2_170.png");
        arrayList.add("http://startandroid.ru/images/stories/pic/banner2_170.png");
        arrayList.add("http://startandroid.ru/images/stories/pic/banner2_170.png");
        progressBar.setMax(arrayList.size());
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        new MyTask().execute(arrayList);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Integer, Void>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            textView.setText("Start");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
            textView.setText(values[0] +"/" +arrayList.size());
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {
            ArrayList<Bitmap> arrayBitmap = new ArrayList<>();
            int i=0;
            for (String imageURL : params[0]){
                try {
                    URL url =new URL(imageURL);
                    InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                    arrayBitmap.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is));
                    String dir = "MyFolder3";
                    String fname = "Image_" +i +".jpg";
                    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(dir), fname);
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    arrayBitmap.get(i).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 65, fos);
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
    //                    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(is, file);
                    i++;
                    publishProgress(i);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            textView.setText("Finish");
        }
    }
}
```

P.s. Я новичок, прошу без заумных терминов) Максимально просто или с пояснениями)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3551906/3212712):

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/dir1/dir2");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "filename");
```

Comment: Не получается( Создает папку и грузит картинки на внутреннюю память

Comment: @T.Kudaibergen, и это так на всех девайсах или только на одном?..

Comment: На других не проверял, вот мой, Lenovo S650 версия Android 4.4.2 API 19

Comment: @T.Kudaibergen, ну, проверьте на других... Вообще должно, вроде, работать. Но роизводители разные часто какую-нить хрень разную городят.